# Swift - Store UIAlterController text value

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

(Using Swift 2 and Xcode 7)

I have a UIAlertController that prompt the user the enter a name.

I'm having difficulties getting the value that the user enters, so any heads up would be great.

I have the following code;

```
func promptUserToEnterSessionName() -> String{

    let sessionNameController = UIAlertController(title: "Save your yoga session", message: "Please enter session name", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = (UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))

    let saveAction = (UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: enteredSessionName))

    sessionNameController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
        (textField) -> Void in
        self.sessionName = textField

    }

    sessionNameController.addAction(cancelAction)
    sessionNameController.addAction(saveAction)
    self.presentViewController(sessionNameController, animated: true, completion: nil)


   //savedSessionName = (sessionNameController.textFields![0] as UITextField).text!
    //print(savedSessionName)

    return ""
}

func enteredSessionName(alert: UIAlertAction!){
        print("sessionName" + String(sessionName))
}
```

Comment: you need to do `self.sessionName = textField.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So another possible solution is to save the whole `UITextField` in your member variable.

```
var textField: UITextField?

sessionNameController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
    (textField) -> Void in
    self.textField = textField
}

func enteredSessionName(alert: UIAlertAction!){
    print("sessionName" + String(self.textField.text))
}
```

Comment: that results in the following error - type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: you could change your member to `UITextField` and save the textField, so you can access the string with textField.text outside the closure